# How to change color scheme in scatter-matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Because I am new to data analysis with python, I want to improve my skills with tutorials and adjusting working code from others.

At the moment I am working on the *fruit_data_with_colors* data set, and want to understand the python code, available at:

https://github.com/susanli2016/Machine-Learning-with-Python/blob/master/Solving%20A%20Simple%20Classification%20Problem%20with%20Python.ipynb

One of the examples at the beginning shows a scatter matrix of the different numeric input variables (height, width, mass, color). With the mentioned code, the colors in the plotted images are purple, brown, yellow and black. I would like to change this to more appealing colors (e.g. red, blue, green, black)

I looked at the documentation of matplotlib and think that I should adjust the `"c = y"` part of my code.
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html

Trying `"c = ['blue']"` worked well, but if I add another color in the form of `"c = ['blue', 'red']"` an error occures:

`ValueError: 'c' argument has 2 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 59, 'y' with size 59.`

````
X = fruits[feature_names]
y = fruits['fruit_label']
from matplotlib import cm
cmap = cm.get_cmap('gnuplot')
scatter = pd.scatter_matrix(X, c = y, marker = 'o', s=40, hist_kwds={'bins':15}, figsize=(9,9), cmap = cmap)
plt.suptitle('Scatter-matrix for each input variable')
plt.savefig('fruits_scatter_matrix')```
````

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to achieve what you want is to change the colormap, just edit:

```
cmap = cm.get_cmap('new_color_map')
```

with a more appealing colormap. You can check the full list [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html). In addition also [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html?highlight=colormap) library provides some nice colormaps. In seaborn you can produce nice scatter matrix plots using the [pairplot function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html#seaborn.pairplot)!

Comment: In particular you can use `cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(["red", "blue", "green", "black"])` to get the colors asked for in the question.